Including specific transitive dependencies in Maven
I know how to exclude transitive properties. What I want to do is the reverse - I want to exclude all, except for a very specific set of dependencies. How does one do that?

Do you want to use this to get around incompatible versions of transitive dependencies? I just ask because transitive dependencies usually are required for the direct dependencies to work, so using a different version by excluding the unwanted version but having a direct dependency to a working version of the transistive dependency is quite common.

Yes. There are situations in which conflicting chained dependencies would cause major problems. There are dozens of projects that work together, someone forgets to update a single dependency, and suddenly conflicts appear. New projects will appear, too. It's easier to maintain an "included" list than dozens of "excluded".

To solve problems with conflicting versions of transitive dependencies, you do NOT use exclusions. Instead, you use <depencencyManagement> to set the transitive version that you need.

Thank you. Did that instead, and it worked.
